# How do I search a PHP array where the needle doesn't exactly match a value?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm using `array_search` to find a key for a certain value.
Example 1 successfully searches the array for the word **green**, but example 2 is trying to find **green** where **Light Green** is a value in the array, but it doesn't work.

Can anyone suggest a way to do this?

```php
//Example 1
$array = array(0 => 'Green', 1 => 'Blue', 2 => 'Black', 3 => 'Yellow');

$key = array_search(strtolower('green'), array_map('strtolower', $array));
//displays 0
echo $key;

//Example 2
$array = array(0 => 'Light Green', 1 => 'Blue', 2 => 'Black', 3 => 'Yellow');

$key = array_search(strtolower('green'), array_map('strtolower', $array));
//should display 0 but displays nothing.
echo $key;
```

Comment: It depends on what you expect. Should for example word `yellowish` match for `yellow`? Or do you only want to split two-word colours, which contain spaces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/array_filter):

```
$array = array(0 => 'Light Green', 1 => 'Blue', 2 => 'Black', 3 => 'Yellow');

$search= 'green';
$key   = key(array_filter($array, function($x) use ($search)
{
   return false!==stripos($x, $search);
}));
```

-note, that code above won't check is passed search string is "word". I.e. it *will* hit `3` for `ellow`

Comment: Just a note that this will accept colors like `yellowish` for the needle `yellow`.

Comment: Yes, I've mentioned that. OP didn't describe that restriction (if any)

Answer (score 2):

There's a wonderful almost unknown PHP function called [fnmatch()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fnmatch.php) that could be useful, it allows wildcarding of expressions and can be combined with [array_filter()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

```
$testData = [
    'green',
    'light green',
    'red',
    'light Green',

];
$testValue = '*green*';

$result = array_filter(
    $testData,
    function($entry) use ($testValue) {
        return fnmatch($testValue, strtolower($entry));
    }
);

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: The only wonder if that'll be faster than `preg_match()` / `stripos()`. Also OP wants _key_ as the result

Comment: To get key(s) as the result, it's easy simply to wrap the whole in an array_keys() as array_filter() retains associativity.... I'll leave others to test whether it's faster or slower than stripos or preg_match().... all I'm doing is showing people that the function actually exists and may be of some value in this use case

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`preg_grep()`](http://php.net/preg_grep) like so:

```
$array = array(0 => 'Light Green', 1 => 'Blue', 2 => 'Black', 3 => 'Yellow');

$matches = preg_grep('/green/i', $array);
```

It returns an array of elements that matched the search expression; to get only the first key:

```
$key = key($matches);
```

To match against a full word, you can add word boundary matches:

```
$matches = preg_grep('/\bgreen\b/i', $array);
```